# Emberjs memory leak in case of nested controller + actions?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I use nested ArrayController in emberjs. Basically I have one parent ArrayController whose content consists of child ArrayControllers. The content of each of this child ArrayController is a list of simple emberjs objects. Monitoring the memory usage of my application using the timeline tool and the profiling tool of Chrome it seems that there are memory leaks when removing child ArrayControllers. I'm using the latest master of emberjs.

The simplified code and demo can be found here http://jsfiddle.net/qVNtv/22/. Clicking on "Add" adds 20 child ArrayController each having 40 simple emberjs objects as children. Clicking on "Remove all" removes all child ArrayController. With each cycle of "Add" and "Remove all" the overall memory usage increases. If I don't use any `{{action}}` the overall memory usage remains constant.

Am I doing anything wrong? Can this increase of memory usage be avoided somehow?

The demo uses an easy template consisting of two nested `{{#each}}`

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  <input type="button" value="Add" onClick="Demo.containerController.addController();"/>
  <input type="button" value="Remove all" onClick="Demo.containerController.removeAll();"/>

  {{#each Demo.containerController.content tagName="ul"}}
    <li>{{#each content}}<a {{action "test"}}></a> {{prop}}{{/each}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</script>
```

The code is

```
  Demo = Ember.Application.create();

  Demo.Model = Ember.Object.extend({
    prop : ''
  });

  Demo.Controller = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    content: []
  });

  Demo.containerController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
    content : [],

    addController : function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        var cnt = [];

        for (var j = 0; j < 40; j++) {
            cnt.pushObject(Demo.Model.create({prop: 'test' + j}));                
        }            

        this.pushObject(
        Demo.Controller.create({
            content: cnt
        }));
      }
    },

    removeAll : function() {          
      this.clear();
    }
  });
```

Comment: Have you tried this in the current master?

Comment: This one https://raw.github.com/emberjs/ember.js/master/lib/ember.js ?
The problems are the same...

Comment: looks like the master I know of this one from the "downloads" [here](https://github.com/downloads/emberjs/ember.js/ember-latest.js). You could try and subscribe to `willRemoveElement` and `willDestroy` and see if they both happen. you could see if you could do some extra cleanup in those methods.

Comment: ah ok ;-) using this latest master fixed the memory problems. Well, at least in the demo code. Thanks.

Comment: do you have any information when the next ember version is going to be released?

Comment: I have no idea they're committing like crazy though :) I read somewhere they want to release a 1.0 in the near future.

Comment: hm memory problem remains when using `{{action}}` in the template

Comment: You should probably report this as an issue on github.

Comment: fyi: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1210